# Why doesn't work Displaylink?

Tags: multiple-monitors, displaylink

I installed displayLink, following in detail, the instructions of this [page](http://support.displaylink.com/knowledgebase/articles/684649-how-to-install-displaylink-software-on-ubuntu)

But, doesn't work. Appanrently  in my pc, all it's ok.

- Displaylink device: Lenovo Enhanced USB Port Replicator usb 2.0.
- Laptop: Lenovo t430
- OS: Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS

I use the following commands in order to active the third monitor:

```
# xrandr --newmode "1024x768_60.00"   63.50  1024 1072 1176 1328  768 771 775 798 -hsync +vsync
# xrandr --addmode DVI-I-1 "1024x768_60.00
```

But, when I put the second command, all screen freeze and the cursor becomes very very slow, then, I restart my pc.

Also used this [script](https://github.com/nathantypanski/displaylink.sh) unsuccessfully.

Also I put the output of some important commands:

xrandr --listproviders

```
# xrandr --listproviders
Providers: number : 2
Provider 0: id: 0x4c cap: 0x9, Source Output, Sink Offload crtcs: 4 outputs: 9 associated providers: 1 name:Intel
Provider 1: id: 0x125 cap: 0x2, Sink Output crtcs: 1 outputs: 1 associated providers: 1 name:modesetting
```

xrandr --current

```
# xrandr --current
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 2732 x 768, maximum 32767 x 32767
LVDS1 connected primary 1366x768+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 309mm x 174mm
   1366x768      59.99*+
   1360x768      59.80    59.96  
   1280x720      60.00  
   1024x768      60.00  
   1024x576      60.00  
   960x540       60.00  
   800x600       60.32    56.25  
   864x486       60.00  
   640x480       59.94  
   720x405       60.00  
   680x384       60.00  
   640x360       60.00  
DP1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP3 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI3 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
VGA1 connected 1366x768+1366+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 410mm x 230mm
   1366x768      59.79*+
   1280x1024     60.02  
   1280x720      60.00  
   1024x768      60.00  
   800x600       60.32  
   640x480       60.00  
   720x400       70.08  
VIRTUAL1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DVI-I-1 connected
   1024x768      75.08    70.07    60.00  
   800x600       72.19    75.00    60.32  
   640x480       75.00    72.81    66.67    60.00  
   720x400       70.08  
  1024x768 (0xef) 65.000MHz -HSync -VSync
        h: width  1024 start 1048 end 1184 total 1344 skew    0 clock  48.36KHz
        v: height  768 start  771 end  777 total  806           clock  60.00Hz
  800x600 (0xf2) 40.000MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width   800 start  840 end  968 total 1056 skew    0 clock  37.88KHz
        v: height  600 start  601 end  605 total  628           clock  60.32Hz
  640x480 (0xfb) 25.200MHz -HSync -VSync
        h: width   640 start  656 end  752 total  800 skew    0 clock  31.50KHz
        v: height  480 start  490 end  492 total  525           clock  60.00Hz
  720x400 (0xfc) 28.320MHz -HSync +VSync
        h: width   720 start  738 end  846 total  900 skew    0 clock  31.47KHz
        v: height  400 start  412 end  414 total  449           clock  70.08Hz
```

Status displaylink.service

```
# systemctl status displaylink.service
● displaylink.service - DisplayLink Manager Service
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/displaylink.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since jue 2016-08-18 23:17:37 VET; 22min ago
  Process: 2656 ExecStartPre=/sbin/modprobe evdi (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 2668 (DisplayLinkMana)
   CGroup: /system.slice/displaylink.service
           └─2668 /usr/lib/displaylink/DisplayLinkManager

ago 18 23:17:36 p1tag0ras systemd[1]: Starting DisplayLink Manager Service...
ago 18 23:17:37 p1tag0ras systemd[1]: Started DisplayLink Manager Service.
```

dmesg output when connect the displaylink device:

```
    [   15.560206] evdi: module verification failed: signature and/or required key missing - tainting kernel
    [   15.561084] evdi: [I] Initialising logging on level 5
    [   15.778509] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp3s0: link is not ready
    [   15.778651] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Disabled
    [   15.786261] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Disabled
    [   15.786360] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Radio type=0x2-0x0-0x0
    [   16.031617] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Disabled
    [   16.039252] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Disabled
    [   16.039348] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Radio type=0x2-0x0-0x0
    [   16.095942] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp3s0: link is not ready
    [   16.099730] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): enp0s25: link is not ready
    [   16.352916] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): enp0s25: link is not ready
    [   16.549009] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp3s0: link is not ready
    [   27.657702] wlp3s0: authenticate with 98:fc:11:ee:53:1d
    [   27.661497] wlp3s0: send auth to 98:fc:11:ee:53:1d (try 1/3)
    [   27.668024] wlp3s0: authenticated
    [   27.669705] wlp3s0: associate with 98:fc:11:ee:53:1d (try 1/3)
    [   27.673221] wlp3s0: RX AssocResp from 98:fc:11:ee:53:1d (capab=0x411 status=0 aid=4)
    [   27.675739] wlp3s0: associated
    [   27.675800] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlp3s0: link becomes ready
    [  150.249300] usb 1-1.2: new high-speed USB device number 5 using ehci-pci
    [  150.342078] usb 1-1.2: New USB device found, idVendor=0409, idProduct=005a
    [  150.342085] usb 1-1.2: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=0, SerialNumber=0
    [  150.342804] hub 1-1.2:1.0: USB hub found
    [  150.343097] hub 1-1.2:1.0: 4 ports detected
    [  150.629377] usb 1-1.2.2: new full-speed USB device number 6 using ehci-pci
    [  150.740068] usb 1-1.2.2: New USB device found, idVendor=0d8c, idProduct=0105
    [  150.740076] usb 1-1.2.2: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=1, SerialNumber=0
    [  150.740080] usb 1-1.2.2: Product: USB Multimedia Audio Device
    [  150.740083] usb 1-1.2.2: Manufacturer: C-Media Electronics Inc.
    [  150.742132] input: C-Media Electronics Inc. USB Multimedia Audio Device as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.2/1-1.2.2/1-1.2.2:1.3/0003:0D8C:0105.0002/input/input18
    [  150.797937] hid-generic 0003:0D8C:0105.0002: input,hidraw1: USB HID v1.00 Device [C-Media Electronics Inc. USB Multimedia Audio Device] on usb-0000:00:1a.0-1.2.2/input3
    [  150.869340] usb 1-1.2.3: new high-speed USB device number 7 using ehci-pci
    [  150.896068] usbcore: registered new interface driver snd-usb-audio
    [  150.978175] usb 1-1.2.3: New USB device found, idVendor=0409, idProduct=005a
    [  150.978179] usb 1-1.2.3: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=0, SerialNumber=0
    [  150.978895] hub 1-1.2.3:1.0: USB hub found
    [  150.979240] hub 1-1.2.3:1.0: 4 ports detected
    [  151.197657] usb 1-1.2.4: new high-speed USB device number 8 using ehci-pci
    [  151.311257] usb 1-1.2.4: New USB device found, idVendor=17e9, idProduct=01e0
    [  151.311265] usb 1-1.2.4: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
    [  151.311268] usb 1-1.2.4: Product: Lenovo Enhanced USB Port Replicator
    [  151.311271] usb 1-1.2.4: Manufacturer: DisplayLink
    [  151.311274] usb 1-1.2.4: SerialNumber: 01>0-147825
    [  151.355318] [drm] vendor descriptor length:e0 data:00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
    [  151.355330] [drm:udl_driver_load [udl]] *ERROR* Unrecognized vendor firmware descriptor
    [  151.463148] udl 1-1.2.4:1.1: fb1: udldrmfb frame buffer device
    [  151.463154] [drm] Supports vblank timestamp caching Rev 2 (21.10.2013).
    [  151.463156] [drm] No driver support for vblank timestamp query.
    [  151.463158] [drm] Initialized udl on minor 1
    [  151.463201] usbcore: registered new interface driver udl
```

lsusb:

```
    Bus 002 Device 003: ID 17ef:6019 Lenovo 
    Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
    Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
    Bus 001 Device 004: ID 04f2:b2da Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd thinkpad t430s camera
    Bus 001 Device 003: ID 147e:2020 Upek TouchChip Fingerprint Coprocessor (WBF advanced mode)
    Bus 001 Device 008: ID 17e9:01e0 DisplayLink 
    Bus 001 Device 007: ID 0409:005a NEC Corp. HighSpeed Hub
    Bus 001 Device 006: ID 0d8c:0105 C-Media Electronics, Inc. CM108 Audio Controller
    Bus 001 Device 005: ID 0409:005a NEC Corp. HighSpeed Hub
    Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
    Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
    Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
    Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

lsusb -v -d 17e9:01e0

```
    Bus 001 Device 008: ID 17e9:01e0 DisplayLink 
    Device Descriptor:
      bLength                18
      bDescriptorType         1
      bcdUSB               2.00
      bDeviceClass          255 Vendor Specific Class
      bDeviceSubClass         0 
      bDeviceProtocol         0 
      bMaxPacketSize0        64
      idVendor           0x17e9 DisplayLink
      idProduct          0x01e0 
      bcdDevice            0.03
      iManufacturer           1 DisplayLink
      iProduct                2 Lenovo Enhanced USB Port Replicator
      iSerial                 3 01>0-147825
      bNumConfigurations      1
      Configuration Descriptor:
        bLength                 9
        bDescriptorType         2
        wTotalLength           48
        bNumInterfaces          2
        bConfigurationValue     1
        iConfiguration          1 DisplayLink
        bmAttributes         0xc0
          Self Powered
        MaxPower                0mA
        Interface Descriptor:
          bLength                 9
          bDescriptorType         4
          bInterfaceNumber        0
          bAlternateSetting       0
          bNumEndpoints           2
          bInterfaceClass       255 Vendor Specific Class
          bInterfaceSubClass      0 
          bInterfaceProtocol      0 
          iInterface              0 
          Endpoint Descriptor:
            bLength                 7
            bDescriptorType         5
            bEndpointAddress     0x01  EP 1 OUT
            bmAttributes            2
              Transfer Type            Bulk
              Synch Type               None
              Usage Type               Data
            wMaxPacketSize     0x0200  1x 512 bytes
            bInterval               0
          Endpoint Descriptor:
            bLength                 7
            bDescriptorType         5
            bEndpointAddress     0x82  EP 2 IN
            bmAttributes            3
              Transfer Type            Interrupt
              Synch Type               None
              Usage Type               Data
            wMaxPacketSize     0x0008  1x 8 bytes
            bInterval               4
        Interface Descriptor:
          bLength                 9
          bDescriptorType         4
          bInterfaceNumber        1
          bAlternateSetting       0
          bNumEndpoints           1
          bInterfaceClass       255 Vendor Specific Class
          bInterfaceSubClass      0 
          bInterfaceProtocol      0 
          iInterface              0 
          Endpoint Descriptor:
            bLength                 7
            bDescriptorType         5
            bEndpointAddress     0x85  EP 5 IN
            bmAttributes            3
              Transfer Type            Interrupt
              Synch Type               None
              Usage Type               Data
            wMaxPacketSize     0x0004  1x 4 bytes
            bInterval              10
    Device Qualifier (for other device speed):
      bLength                10
      bDescriptorType         6
      bcdUSB               2.00
      bDeviceClass          255 Vendor Specific Class
      bDeviceSubClass         0 
      bDeviceProtocol         0 
      bMaxPacketSize0        64
      bNumConfigurations      1
    Device Status:     0x0001
      Self Powered
```